# Gensim training meaningless word embeddings

Tags: nlp, gensim, embedding, word-embedding, fasttext

The word embeddings when training with Gensim are meaningless: the similarities on known relationships (King - Man + Woman -> Queen) and others simply don't hold (not even close), they might as well be random.

Using the same training data and equivalent parameters, I get meaningful results with Facebook's FastText. In comparison, I've tried the Gensim FastText and Word2Vec classes, both returning meaningless embeddings.

To narrow things down, here are some of the settings:

- 30GB training data text file. Space separated tokens, newline separated sentences.
- Final vocab size after training: 12M+ word vectors
- Dimension = 100
- Disabled subwords
- Disabled n-grams
- Negative sampling = 8
- Skip-gram
- Min-count = 20

Training code below:

```py
print("Setting Model")
model = FastText(
# model = Word2Vec(
  sg=1,
  size=dim, 
  max_vocab_size=max_vocab_size,
  window=10, 
  negative=8,
  min_count=20,
  max_n=0,
  min_n=0,
  workers=16,
  alpha=0.1,
)
print("Building vocab")
model.build_vocab(
  corpus_file=corpus_file,
  progress_per=1_000_000
)
print("Training model")
model.train(
  corpus_file=corpus_file,
  total_words=model.corpus_total_words,
  total_examples=model.corpus_count,
  epochs=5,
  word_ngrams=0,
)
print("Saving model")
model.save(model_name)
```

I would rather avoid using Facebook's FastText as it would require me changing its source code to achieve this vocab size.

What could be going wrong, or how can I debug this? I have been able to import Facebook's FastText vectors into Gensim and it works fine.

Comment: That's odd, because the marquee example `model.most_similar(positive=['king', 'woman'], negative=['man'])` typically gives meaningful answers even when trained on something like the 1GB `text8` (`enwik8`) text set. So, there's something amiss with your setup. Have you enabled logging at the INFO level & examined the logs for any anomalous progress-reporting? Can you add more about your `corpus_file` to the question – such as what `wc CORPUS_FILE` & `head -1 CORPUS_FILE | wc` show, & `head -1 CORPUS_FILE` if you can share?

Comment: Other observations about your code, not necessarily related to your problem: You probably don't want to be using `max_vocab_size` (& haven't shown what value you're using).  Both `negative=8` & `alpha=0.1` are atypical values; it's always odd to see such variations in cases where the basics aren't even working. Gensim's `train()` method doesn't use a `word_ngrams` – so its appearance is odd, too. If you'd prefer to use `Word2Vec` & can see the problem there, I'd suggest editing your question code to focus on that case, without FT-complications.

Comment: the vocabulary size is typically within a few hundred thousands... u said that ur vocab size is 12M... which makes me think that there's some tokenization error... did u check if the words are well formed?

Comment: While it's certainly possible to seek a 12M word final vocabulary - that's pretty rare with actual natural-language data, in my experience. (The 300d `GoogleNews` vectors Google released in 2013 were trained on "around 100B" words" – but they still kept only the 3 million most-common words/phrases, and the tail is already very obscure low-value stuff. And, they gave the model 300-dimensions to work with.

Comment: If your tokens are ~6 bytes each, 300GB is only 5B 'words' of training, of which you're retaining '12M+', but only giving them 100-dimensions, there may be other issues in vocab-to-model fit, from tokenization or other choices. . Perhaps, this isn't natural-lang training data? (Word2Vec etc often is useful for non-natural-lang data, but without usual word-distributions/co-occurrences, usual assumptions about useful metaparameters, or expected results, may not hold.) Is it really the `wv['king'] - wv['man'] + wv['woman']` result you're testing, & if so how, & is the training data English text?

Comment: @gojomo the training data is natural language mixed with IDs: the IDs should represent most of the vectors, and it's useful to have them associated with natural language.
I managed to work around this issue by changing the FastText source to allow for a larger vocab, and convert to Gensim format so it can be memmapped. I'm still curious why Gensim won't train properly (using same params as fasttext).

Comment: @debasis yes, the resulting vocabulary makes sense, so tokens are well formed. The input .txt is composed of lines of text, with each word separated by space. It's exactly the input for FastText, which if I'm not mistaken is the same as Gensim's, correct?

Comment: Additionally, it's hard to experiment: this takes 17 hours to train, on a 120GB ram/ 16 core machine. Any ideas on how I should run the next experiment to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Just in the last few days, I've found a gensim bug when using its `FastText` class without n-grams (eg `max_n=0`). (That's a less-typical usage for which people would normally just use plain `Word2Vec`.) Not sure if that's related to your issue, since you also said you had the same problem with `Word2Vec`, but as above: if you don't need the `FastText` features, and/or are just trying to demo a problem that occurs both places, you should edit your question/test-code to focus on just `Word2Vec` for simplicity.

Comment: As mentioned before, the usual 'king - man + woman' example can be demonstrated on tiny text training sets, which train in a few minutes. So until you've gotten at least that much working (assuming you have relevant texts in your data), you should be testing things with a much smaller dataset, and when you're sure basic word-similarities/relationships are working, only then scale up to multi-hour training sessions. What words & code, exactly, are you using the decide such analogies aren't working?

Comment: Also, there aren't many limits in the gensim source on vocabulary size – practically, it's limited only by available RAM. So I don't know what's meant by "changing the FastText source to allow for a larger vocab". (Do you mean the FB 'fasttext' tool source or Gensim source, & what did the changes involve?) Also, any mention of making it "so it can be memmapped" raises concerns: that's an optimization that'd typically only become important later, after ensuring basic functionality – so any problems could be a result of your (unshown) source edits. Can you reproduce problem in unchanged Gensim?

Comment: @gojomo Yes, I meant I had to change Facebook's fastText, only to increase the vocab limit. With this method I have been able to guarantee it's well functioning. Because FB's fastText does not support `mmap` with its own format, the solution was to convert it to the gensim format (using `load_facebook_vectors` and `model.save`). I then load it as a `gensim.models.KeyedVectors` with mmap, so it doesn't consume an enormous amount of memory.
An additional benefit of this method is it only takes a third of the time to train.

Comment: @gojomo for the analogy I used the example in the documentation: `word_vectors.most_similar(positive=['woman', 'king'], negative=['man'])`.
That's a sensible idea: I will attempt it again, with a much smaller fraction of the full training set.

Comment: OK, yes, `mmap` could offer benefits in deployment – especially if multiple processes load same set-of-vectors – but not necessarily in training (unless something else is going wrong). The `king - man + woman` will require your text to include uses of those words in their normal meanings – if your domain is something very different, it might not work. Unless you specifically need the FastText ability to synthesize guess vectors for OOV words – which `max_n=0` disables – I'd avoid it through `gensim-3.8.3`, due to both the bug I mentioned above, & other bugs where it uses way too much memory.